# read multiple sensor with serial port programming C

Tags: c, input, serial-port

I want to read data from an Arduino micro controller to my pc running Mac OS X via serial port with the C programming language and the GCC compiler.

The format of my data is `A xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx B`, with A is the beginning of the data, B is the end of the data and between the sensor there are 4 space (" ").
The xxxx data vary vary between 0-1023.

I am trying this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include<unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include<fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include<errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include<termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include<string.h> 
#include<unistd.h>

char *buf;
int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
int i,n;
char *sensor1, *sensor2, *sensor3, *sensor4, *sensor5, *sensor6,*header, *footer;

int open_port(void)
{
    fd = open("/dev/tty.usbmodem1d11", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);      

if (fd == -1)     {
    perror("cannot open");
}
else 
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; 
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
//    options.c_cflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // xon & xoff on
return (fd);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    buf=malloc(4095);
    open_port();
    free(buf);
    while(1){ 
        read(fd,buf,90);          
         printf("%s\n",buf);  
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

But the result is not consistent, I mean the length of the data is not the same:

A      1023    1023    1023    1023    1023       B

A

10233   023    1023    1023       B

A      1023    1023    1023    1023    1023       B

A 
    3   023    1023    1023       B

A      1023    1023    1023    1023    1023       B

A

10233   023    1023    1023       B

A      1023    1023    1023    1023    1023       BA

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ccheck the return value from read(). read may return before it has obtained the number of bytes you intended to read.

Comment: Also, don't assume the contents of buffer are nul-terminated; you cannot just call `printf("%s", buffer);` with the resulting buffer, printf()s "%s" expects a nul-terminated string.

Comment: why do you free the buffer before using it?  That is not what it causing your problem, but it wont help later on...

Comment: Also, try reading more than 90 bytes - eg read 1024. I have a feeling your reading is not keeping up with the data stream.  What is your plaform?

Comment: I change the free buffer before close fd, but nothing change

Comment: My micro is arduino, I program with c compiler gcc with max os. I change the buffer but the data still not stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine what you are getting back from each read call:

```
int nbytes;

while(1) { 
    nbytes = read(fd,buf,90);
    if( nbytes > 0 ) {
        buf[nbytes] = 0;
        printf( "Read %2d bytes: '%s'\n", nbytes, buf );
    }
}
```

You will need to gather the result into a buffer, and parse it according to your device's format specification.  You can't just assume that each `read` call will give you a whole record.

To gather the result, you need to keep track of what you have already read - something like this...

```
int nbytes, nparsed;
int npos = 0;

while(1) { 
    nbytes = read(fd, &buf[npos], 90-npos);
    if( nbytes > 0 )
    {
        npos += nbytes;

        // Parse a line.  If successful, move remainder of line to
        // start of buffer and continue...
        nparsed = parse_line(buf, npos);
        if( nparsed > 0 ) {
            memmove( buf, &buf[npos], npos-nparsed );
            npos -= nparsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Depends on your application.  It might be even simpler than that.

Comment: thank for the advise, the result look like this:

Read  4 bytes 'A   '
 Read  4 bytes '1023'
 Read  4 bytes '    '
 Read  4 bytes '1023'
 Read  4 bytes '    '
 Read  4 bytes '1023'
 Read  4 bytes '    '
 Read  3 bytes '0  '
 Read  4 bytes '  10'
 Read  4 bytes '23  '
 Read  4 bytes '  0 '
 Read  4 bytes '    '
 Read  4 bytes '  B
'
still do not stable

Comment: the result is for the first program.
for the second program, I still looking for header for command parse_line

Comment: `parse_line` was an example of a function that *you* might write to handle the line.  I don't know the details of how you would interpret data from your device, so I just put in something generic to illustrate how to collect data from a port and then use it.

Comment: if I change with other program, like I send 0 than the micro send data from analog 0, and so on..
I use :

open_port();
        
        write(fd,"0",1);
        read(fd,buf0,10);
        printf(" %s \n",buf0);
        usleep(100);
        
        write(fd,"1",1);
        read(fd,buf1,10);
        printf(" %s \n",buf1);
        usleep(100);}
but there are no result in the monitor.